# Clone compiled cmake build to identical hardware

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi

I have successfully compiled opencv 3.1 on a raspberry pi. Developing with the library works perfectly fine. Now I wanted to set up another, identical raspberry with opencv and to save the compilation time, my idea was to copy the binaries to the second raspberry.

So I copied the opencv directories including the build folder and tried to run `sudo make install`. Instead of using the already compiled files, compilation using cmake starts over again.

How can I convince the second raspberry's build environent that there is no need to recompile everything? On my original raspberry, I can run `sudo make install` on the exactly same files without recompilation. Installed dev-libraries are the same on both systems. Is this a cmake, make or a opencv specific problem?

I also tried to copy all .so and .h files from `/usr/...` directories, but then I run into further problems when other cmake projects try to locate the opencv package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Build* directory is not intended to be copied into other place or on another machine.

For deliver program to other machine you should use *installed* files, or, more generally, a **package**.

CMake is shipped with [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cpack.1.html), which can build the program from sources and create *package* contained all its deliverables.

You may create `.deb` package on the first Raspberry PI machine:

```
cpack -G DEB <source-dir>
```

and install it on the second machine using `dpkg`.

There are also "archive" packages like `.tgz` or `.zip`. Full list of CPack generators is described in [wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators).

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed! Running cpack with the DEB option fails with a weird error message, so I used `-G TGZ` and unpacked the archive on the second machine.

The error message of cpack is (for the sake of completeness): `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake:294 (string): string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to command.`